# Calling javascript function's result into Jquery css event, on load and resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call `logoSocialHeight()` function's result into `$('header.main').css('top',logoSocialHeight()).hover(`

It should only trigger this when the window loads or viewport will be resized. I try to call everything here below 1600px screen resolution. However `logoSocialHeight()` only works if I first loading the webpage more than 1600px resolution, than I shrink it down to below 1600px and it will be triggered, otherwise not.

Is there a Jquery way of `window.addEventListener`s, like with `$(window).on('load resize'`?

```
function logoSocialHeight() {
  var logoHeight = $('header.main .logo').outerHeight(true);
  var socialHeight = $('header.main .social-links').outerHeight(true);
  var sum = -Math.abs(logoHeight + socialHeight - 10);
  console.log(sum);
  return sum;
};
window.addEventListener('load', logoSocialHeight, false);
window.addEventListener('resize', logoSocialHeight, false);

function bindNavUp() {
  var lastScrollTop = 0, delta = 5;

  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta) {
      return;
    };

    if (st > lastScrollTop) {
      // downscroll code
      $('header.main').css('top',logoSocialHeight()).hover(
        function() {
          $('header.main').css('top','0');
        }
      );
    }
    else {
      // upscroll code
      $('header.main').css('top','0');
    };
    lastScrollTop = st;
  });
};
function unbindNavUp() {
  $(window).unbind('scroll');
};
function handleNavUp() {
  if ($(window).width() < 1600) {
    bindNavUp();
  }
  else {
    unbindNavUp(); 
  };
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  var timer;
  $(window).on('load resize scroll', function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      handleNavUp();  
    }, 100);
  });
  handleNavUp();
});
```

UPDATE:

Working, simplified code:

```
function logoSocialHeight() {
  var logoHeight = $('header.main .logo').outerHeight(true);
  var socialHeight = $('header.main .social-links').outerHeight(true);
  var sum = -Math.abs(logoHeight + socialHeight - 10);
  //console.log(sum);
  return sum;
};
function bindNavUp() {
  var lastScrollTop = 0, delta = 5;
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta) {
      return;
    };

    if (st > lastScrollTop) {
      // downscroll code
      $('header.main').css('top',logoSocialHeight()).hover(
        function() {
          $('header.main').css('top','0');
        }
      );
    }
    else {
      // upscroll code
      $('header.main').css('top','0');
    };
    lastScrollTop = st;
  });
};
function unbindNavUp() {
  $(window).unbind('scroll');
};
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
  if ($(this).width() < 1600) {
    bindNavUp();
  }
  else {
    unbindNavUp();
  };
});
```

Comment: So is the issue that the `.css()` isn't being called on the `load/resize` events? If so, is there a reason you wouldn't call it in `myFunction`?

Comment: It is called and works flawlessly, only if I load my page upper resolution than 1600px and shrink it down below 1600px. But the problem is, it has to only work below 1600px every time. I'm using Jquery 3 beta git channel.

Comment: I simplified my question, removed `myFunction`.

Comment: There is a way you can bind it to those events. I don't know it off by heart, but just keep looking it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I would comment but sadly am < 50 rep so I am not allowed to and am forced to write here. I am not sure if this will help you since I am not too familiar with JQuery, however when you are adding event listeneers in plain JavaScript you cannot use parentheses "()" while registering. You need to only name the function.

```
$('header.main').css('top',logoSocialHeight).hover(
```

Comment: It works just like if I use double parentheses: only working if I first load the page over 1600px and shrink it down below 1600px.  It should only work below 1600px, even if I load the page first below this resolution.

Comment: I will assume this behavior is linked to the way you are dealing with your timer. You might be clearing it before it gets to act. Try to remove clearing of the timer completely for the test purposes.

Comment: Thank You, removing timer looks like solved it. Now I use `$(window).on('load resize', function() { handleNavUp(); });`. After a few scrolling, I've got 50-100 event fires. Is it normal or something counting too many times? Can this cause performance loss?

Comment: It is fired a lot because even the slightest of movements gets the event fired, so you have the function fired a lot of times, as for performance issues, I wouldn't say it is too hard, the functions do not really do too much, but I could be wrong, someone with more experience needs to asnwer that.

Comment: If you want to make sure the performance is not hindered, make a different function call, one that checks if a certain object is present, if it is not, creates it and sets the new value within, then 100 milliseconds later does whatever the function needs to do if the value in the object doesn't fit the one on the page, that way you will still be firing the function many times, but only thing it would do is change 1 single property of an object and that is certainly not hindering performance. Just remember to kill the object later.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/oejhaz7y/1/ Here is a JSFiddle example of what I mean. now yes I know, using global objects is a sacrilege, if you have any unifier object in your project, hook this into it. Alternatively, remove the event handler from the element once the first event is fired, and after a timer expires add it back again (this works if you really wanna avoid a global object)